# Disabled Arc now loads of bugs

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting, sharekit

I have been trying to use ShareKit in my project,  but it came up ARC restrictions so I've disable ARC in all the share kit files  using the`-fno-objc-arc`compiler flag.

But now I've turned off arc theres loads of errors and issues. Does anyone know a solution to this or do i have to debug all the code  ?

Also I've looked on the web but can't seem to find it but does an ARC compatible version of share kit exist  ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do yourself a favor and don't disable ARC. ;) what version of ShareKit did you try? I just found [this one](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit) and it seems to be ARCified (can't tell for sure since I'm on mobile, but I couldn't find any release calls, so either it's using ARC or leaking :D - I assume it's the former). ;)

Comment: haha ok thanks ! ill check it out and ill let everyone know cheers for the quick response !

Answer (score 0):

The errors are probably due to using the `weak` qualifier for a property in one of your Objective C classes being synthesized in a non-ARC class: MRC can't do this. Instead, use `unsafe_unretained` or the MRC equivalent `assign`.

Remember, the Clang Static Analyzer is your friend, especially for MRC and CoreFoundation code.